# Deploying Jar file no main class found eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Hi I have seen some threads about the problem. But none of them solved my problem.

When using the Export option from exlipse selecting jar I configure it like this:

[Jar Export Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ulVJ.png)

[Jar Export Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bAWO.png)

so far so good, the Main class is detected. But then when trying to run the jar I get the error:

"Java Virtual Machine Launcher" 
"Could not find the main class: Program will exit."

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My Manifest file looks like this:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main

Comment: your Main class is in the default package (no package) ? Did you try to open the jar to see if the Main class an the manifest file are there ?

Comment: Can you show directory structure of your jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jar export, make sure to check the src folder under the selected projet and check the last 3 options export and uncheck the first one. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe this was all I had to do!